# Why don't my locale settings in number_to_currency work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Per the [Rails 3.2 API Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.16/), to use different locales for `number_to_currency`, I need to do the following:

```
<%= number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => :fr) %>
```

I was expecting the following output:

```
# => 1 234 567 890,51 €
```

Even though I literally use that exact thing within my app and it keeps outputting the following:

```
$1,234,567,890.51
```

When I check for the `available_locales` within my app I get the following:

```
> I18n.available_locales
=> [:en, :de, :es, :fr, :ja, :pl, :"pt-BR", :ru, :sv, :"zh-CN"]
```

So it SHOULD work, but it doesn't.

What am I missing?

**Update 1**

Per @s3tjan's comment, I did some digging in that linked Rails issue and that led me to my `application.rb` where I discovered `I18n.enforce_available_locales = false`. I changed that to true and restarted the server.

When I tried the above again, I am now getting this error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (:fr is not a valid locale):
```

Not sure how to fix this.

**Update 2**

So I just realize that I never had a locale file in my `config/locales`. What I really want is to use the GBP Pounds for currency, so I added an `en-GB.yml` file in my `config/locales`, then I restarted my server and console.

In my `application.rb`, I have the following:

```
I18n.enforce_available_locales = true
```

Then I checked my console and got this:

```
[1] pry(main)> I18n.available_locales
=> [:en, :de, :es, :fr, :ja, :pl, :"pt-BR", :ru, :sv, :"zh-CN", :"en-GB"]
[2] pry(main)>
```

So the `:"en-GB"` was added successfully to my app's load path.

But when I do this in my view:

```
<%= number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => :"en-GB") %>
```

This is the error I get:

```
:"en-GB" is not a valid locale excluded from capture due to environment or should_capture callback

ActionView::Template::Error (:"en-GB" is not a valid locale):
```

So still not working.

**Update 3**

My `en-GB.yml` file was taken directly from https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml

So it looks exactly like that. Yet I am still getting the same error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (:"en-GB" is not a valid locale):
```

Comment: It works fine on `Rails 5.2` could be an issue with your Rails version. Check issue #117 https://github.com/r18n/r18n/issues/117

Comment: @s3tjan I checked it out and updated my question with what I found.

Comment: Whats the content of your `en-GB.yml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Synopsis:***

Remove custom language ymls and add the correct version of the [i18n-rails](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) gem. This resolved this special issue.

***Original answer:***

Ok my guess is that your en-GB.yml is empty. So it actually finds the file and adds the locale in `I18n.available_locales` BUT this does not include that all translations are available.

When you look at the format of such a yml [file](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/master/rails/locale/en-GB.yml) you will recognize they all start with

```
---
language-code
  some_keys: ...
```

This is what actually is loaded into memory and therefore provides all the available translations. Available locale is just defined by found files in `config/locales`.

When you check the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ed70c591fa086d745b35a16713d91fc0e3ec858/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L136) of `number_to_currency` It takes the locale from the options and passes it along the key it looks for to I18n.

```
I18n.translate(:'number.format', :locale => options[:locale], :default => {})
```

Since you just say that `en-GB` is available but don't have the actual keys along the locale in memory you get the missing translation issue.

What I suggest is you either use the content of the linked yml file and paste it into your en-GB.yml or you remove your en-GB.yml and find a 3.2 working [i18n-rails](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n) version and use it. i18n-rails provides plenty of default translations which are utilized all over default rails.

*Addition*:
Before you added the en-GB.yml file it actually worked like expected.
When no locale is found it defaults to dollar in [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5ed70c591fa086d745b35a16713d91fc0e3ec858/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/number_helper.rb#L145) since the `currency` variable will be just and empty `{}`.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect what my `en-GB.yml` looks like. I haven't gotten a chance to read your full response yet, I have to run on the road, but I wanted to just update that in the meanwhile.

Comment: Since you are on 3.2 better use: https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/rails-3-x/rails/locale/en-GB.yml and not the master version.

Comment: Ok...so I finally got a chance to read the entire answer. Yeah, that's pretty much what I did. I just replaced the `en-GB.yml` with the 3.2 version but I am still getting the error: `ActionView::Template::Error (:"en-GB" is not a valid locale):` Thoughts?

Comment: Can you try to remove your yml file and just use `gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 3.0'`. Does this work?

Comment: Also you can try afterwards this https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13164#issuecomment-39744133

Comment: Finally got it working. Your suggestion to remove my yml file and just use the `rails-i18n` gem worked like a charm. If you edit your answer and add it as your final answer, I will accept it. Thanks for all the work helping me debug this.

Comment: Lovely to hear that you got it working :) Made a small synopsis just in case someone  ever got the same issue.

Comment: Great. I also gave you a bounty cuz the other one expired. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Somehow, I found the solution that worked for me.

First of all, you need to have a locale file with your requirements in it.

Here is the example of [fr.yml](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/edit/master/rails/locale/fr.yml) file

For an instance, copy and paste this file in app/config/locales/

then restart your console,

then try,  number_to_currency(1000.51, locale: :fr)

for sure, you will get '1 000,51 €'

[Here](https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/tree/master/rails/locale) is the full list of all supported countries' locale file.

Until and unless you don't have locale file with your format required in it, you won't get the desired result.

Comment: I tried this, but `number_to_currency` doesn't work in my console for some reason. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

my rails version is 3.2.22.5, ruby is 2.4.2(I didnt install below 2.x.x)

I use locale yml from 
https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/rails-3-x/rails/locale/en-GB.yml

This is work well

```
 <%= number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => :"en-GB") %>

 <%= number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => "en-GB") %>
```

to result

```
£1,234,567,890.51
```

and I add fr.yml too like

```
fr:
  ...
  number:
    currency:
      format:
        ...
        unit: €
```

And then this is work too

```
<%= number_to_currency(1234567890.506, :locale => :fr) %>
```

to result

€1,234,567,890.51

I didn't change or add configuration. I add only controller, view and locale file. And test it.

You could translate directly like, so test this

```
I18n.translate(:'number.currency.format', :locale => "en-GB", :default => {})
```

if it occur a same error, then check out you file's **name, extension, path**.

and you must restart server

Comment: Nope...this doesn't work. I still get the error `"en-GB" is not a valid locale excluded from capture due to environment or should_capture callback
ActionView::Template::Error ("en-GB" is not a valid locale):`